# SOQL - How to query for opps which are not lost ( but not using stagename)

Tags: soql

I am looking to query for all open and won opps, but i dont want to use the stagename as there multiple closed-Lost stages and there could couple more added later. I dont want to change the query everytime there is a new stage added in.

```
WHERE stagename not IN('Closed-Lost','Closed-Lost-NoBudget')
```

is there a way to get the records without explicitly specifying stagename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the stage properly linked to the Won-Lost, maybe by...

```
SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE IsWon = true OR IsClosed = false
```

Comment: Adding `IsWon` purely makes this answer *less* efficient.

Comment: @Adrian Larson, can you elaborate a bit more your thought and reasons? (So everybody can benefit from it in the future)

Answer (score 4):

How about selecting all, that don't contain "Closed" in their stage name:

```
WHERE stagename LIKE '%Won%' OR (NOT stagename LIKE '%Closed%')
```

Comment: This would include closed/won as well. i need to have closedwon and exclude only closed lost ones

Comment: @Prady updated my answer to include all wons. You could also write 'Closed-Lost%' if they all have the same prefix